# Flink batch program output accumulator doesn't work

Tags: apache-flink, flink-batch

```
    ExecutionEnvironment env = ExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment();
    ......
    JobExecutionResult jobExecutionResult = env.execute(XXXOffline.class.getName());
    int records = jobExecutionResult.<Integer>getAccumulatorResult("counter");
    LOGGER.info("total records: {}", records);
```

However the log was not written to the log file(ps: other log output works well). I think env.execute() is blocking call and when all subtasks are over the getAccumulatorResult() executes. I don't know why the last line log output doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

From the [docs](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.10/dev/api_concepts.html#accumulators--counters), you can see that

> Accumulators are simple constructs with an add operation and a final accumulated result, which is available after the job ended.

So as you have figured out, there is no way to access the accumulator before the job terminated (e.g., env#execute returns). They can be used to orchestrate smaller (bounded) jobs. I often use it for integration tests to formulate assertions.

For unbounded jobs, they have no clear benefit. You want to use [metrics](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-stable/monitoring/metrics.html) instead.

Comment: My program is a dataset batch program. After env.execute() returned I should get accumulator result and log it. But actually it's not.

Comment: There are several examples in terms of (tests)[https://github.com/apache/flink/blob/master/flink-tests/src/test/java/org/apache/flink/test/accumulators/AccumulatorITCase.java] in Flink, which you can use to double-check your solution. But the log line should still occur. I rather suspect that you misconfiured your logger. You could also use a debugger to check what's really going on.

Comment: Thx. It's probably the problem of the flink cluster. Program started from local IDE works as expected.